# What is the best way to display and edit a large array of hex data in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, ui-design

I am looking to display an array from 128 to 512 bytes in size of hexadecimal data (0x00 to 0xFF) in a 16 X n grid-like display.  It needs the capability of selecting a single element or group of elements and highlighting the data in some way.  It also needs to allow editing. I'm writing this in C# 3,5 using Winforms.

I'm considering some kind of rich text box or just an array of small textboxes, but neither idea is without its drawbacks.  Is there a free spreadsheet-like custom control that makes sense, or am I going to have to roll my own.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the DataGridView.

You'd need to break this up into the constituent cells, but it definitely is great for putting together a grid of data (like Excel).

Answer (score 1):

better approach will be to create a custom control like little label, with all the bells and whistles to show highlighted one and editing and putting all of these in custom container like panel. you can specify row and column for your custom label for easier layout.